# How to add attributes to json exception response in rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-5

When I call a service in my api REST app for example "localhost/api/boxes/56" with an id value who doesn't exists in my data base I get a RecordNotFoundException and the json rendered looks like:

```
{
  "status": 404,
  "error": "Not Found",
  "exception": "#<ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find Box with 'id'=56>",
  "traces": {
    "Application Trace": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "trace": "app/controllers/api/v1/boxes_controller.rb:47:in `set_box'"
      }
    ],
    "Framework Trace": [
      {
        "id": 0,
        "trace": "activerecord (5.0.2) lib/active_record/core.rb:173:in `find'"
      },...
    ],
    "Full Trace": [
      {
        "id": 0,
        "trace": "activerecord (5.0.2) lib/active_record/core.rb:173:in `find'"
      },...
    ]
  }
}
```

How and what class have I to override to add a "message" attribute in this exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can handle if the record isn't found through your own validation, if you're trying to get a record in your database through the id or any other maybe as:

```
record = Record.find(params[:id])
```

Then you can check if that record is `nil`, because it couldn't be found, maybe a bad request, then render the json as you want, something like:

```
if !record.nil?
  render json: record, status: 200
else
  render json: bad_request
end
```

And the bad_request method is defined within the `ApplicationController` like:

```
def bad_request
  {
    error: 'Record not found, maybe a bad request',
    status: 400
  }
end
```

Or if in the other hand, you want to handle and set your own response to that behavior directly on your method which is being fired then you can `rescue` the `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` exception, like:

```
def show
  box = Box.find(params[:id])
  render json: box, status: 200
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
  render json: { error: 'Baaaaaad' }
end
```

Also if you want to make this action available for all your models you can use the `rescue_from` method within your `ApplicationController` and to set the exception to "catch" and then the method which will respond with, like:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  ...
  rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, with: :damn_nothing_found

  def damn_nothing_found
    render json: { error: 'nothing found :c' }, status: :not_found
  end
end
```

Comment: Cada opción está mejor que la anterior, muchas gracias pequeño :*

Comment: Jajaja de nada!.